# How can I see who (if anyone) has a certain tag badge?

Tags: support, tag-badges

If I have earned a tag badge, I can easily click on the badge and see a list of who else has earned it.

But, suppose I want to see who (if anyone) earned the bronze [pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch) tag badge. Because each tag badge page URL uses both the tag name *and badge id*, e.g. for [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python):

https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/267/python

unless I know the id number for the PyTorch bronze badge, I cannot access it directly.

Is there a (preferably easy) navigational path for me to either reach that page if it exists **or** know that the badge has not been created yet if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start by viewing its [all-time top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pytorch/topusers). Since all the top users don't have enough rep on the subject to get a bronze badge, no-one will have enough rep.

If there would've been a top user that had that badge, you could've clicked through from there.

Answer (score 13):

You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> any tag-badge [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags):

[image]

Clicking on the badge icon will show you a list of users with it; if it does not appear on this page, no users have earned it yet.

---

Alternatively, if you yourself have the badge, navigate to:

<kbd>[My profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3990607/patapouf-ai)</kbd> → <kbd>[Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3990607/patapouf-ai?tab=topactivity)</kbd> → <kbd>[Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3990607/patapouf-ai?tab=badges)</kbd> →  <kbd>[pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7940/pytorch?userid=3990607)</kbd> → [Others with this badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7940/pytorch)

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind having a lag of up to 7 days, this [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/811426?tagname=pytorch&class=2) will do the trick:

```sql
-- class: Gold/Silver/Bronze "1 = Gold; 2 = Silver; 3 = Bronze; 0 = All"

select userid [User Link]
     , Date
     , case class 
       when 1 then '1. Gold'
       when 2 then '2. Silver'
       when 3 then '3. Bronze'
       end [Metal class] 
from badges
where tagbased = 1
and name = ##tagname:string?pytorch##
and class = case when ##class?0## <> 0 then ##class## else class end
order by [date] desc
```

Notice that you can enter both the tagname and the class (Gold/Silver/Bronze) where class also accepts 0 to include all classes. Hover over the label to see the other valid values.

[image: SEDE query parameter form with labels tagname and value pytorch and gold/silver/bronze with value2. Button Run Query, options: text-only results, label switch to meta site, results tab with 3 columns: User Link; date; Class. First row; column 1: link to jodag; column2: 2021-03-19 19:35:50; column3: 2. Silver]